# Finding the sum of a geometric progression

Tags: python, sum, sequence

I'm being asked to add the first 100 terms f the sequence (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ...etc)

what i ve been trying is something Iike

```
for x in range(101): 
    n = ((1)/(2**x))        
    sum(n)
```

gives me an error, guess you cant put ranges to a power

```
print(n)
```

will give me a list of all the values, but i need them summed together

anyone able to give me a hand?

using qtconsole if that's of any relevance, i'm quite new to this if you haven't already guessed

Comment: "gives me an error" - well, don't make us guess then. What is the error?

Comment: write `n=0` before the loop and only put `n+=((1)/(2**x))`

Comment: don't have the error written down, I can only use Python at college, i believe the problem was It was unable to put a "range" to pow(), **. can't really add anymore than that

Comment: Alright percusse, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, there is actually a formula for sum of geometric series:

[image: Sum of GS]

In your question, `a` is 1, `r` is 0.5 and `n` is 100

So we can do like

```py
a = 1
r = 0.5
n = 100

print(a * (1 - r ** n) / (1 - r))
```

Answer (score 2):

**You keep only one value at a time**. If you want the sum, you need to **aggregate the results**, and for that you'd need an **initial value**, to which you can **add each round the current term**:

```
n = 0  # initial value
for x in range(100):
    n += 1 / 2**x # add current term
print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to initialize sum_n to zero. With each iteration, you add (1/2**x) from your sequence/series to sum_n until you reach n_range.

```
n_range = 101
sum_n = 0  # initialize sum_n to zero

for x in range(n_range):
    sum_n +=  (1/(2**x))

print(sum_n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because sum takes an iterable and you are passing it a float:

sum(iterable[, start])

To solve your problem, as others have suggested, you need to init an accumulator and add your power on every iteration.

If you absolutely must use the sum function:

```
>>> import math
>>> sum(map(lambda x:math.pow(2,-x),range(100)))
2.0
```